# This is a question about IBM quantum circuit used to generate the quantum cheque state

Tags: ibm-q-experience, entanglement, ibm-quantum-devices

I'm learning about quantum cheque. And I read ["Experimental realization of quantum cheque using a five-qubit quantum computer"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00182.pdf) which is written by Bikash K. Behera ,Anindita Banerjee and Prasanta K. Panigrahi.
Then I have a question about FIG.5 in this paper. FIG.5 shows IBM quantum circuit used to generate the quantum cheque state.
Is this a quantum circuit where the bank is passing one entangled qubit in a GHZ triplet state to the account holder?

**The mentioned FIG.5:**

[image: FIG. 5.]

Comment: If you could add a link to the paper and a picture of the figure you mention, that would make it easier for people to answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. This is a link for a picture of the quantum circuit.
https://imgur.com/a/QpZpFuw

Answer (score 0):

From the paper: "In Figure 5, the first three qubits are in possession of Alice, the Bank contains the fifth qubit, and the fourth qubit remains unused."

Alice's bits two and three are "provided" by the bank; they are part of a GHZ state. So, the account holder gets two -- not three -- qubit of the GHZ state.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'm starting to understand it thanks to your answer and this Quantum Protocol Zoo page. https://wiki.veriqloud.fr/index.php?title=Quantum_Cheque
The Quantum Protocol Zoo page says "The bank then prepares n GHZ triplet states and stores only the third entangled qubit of every GHZ in the database, while handing over the first two qubits of every GHZ state to the account holder. Along with this, the bank also creates and shares a corresponding unique serial number for this cheque." in Outline.

Comment: So in FIG.5 , the account holder has q[0] and q[1]. And the bank has q[4] which is swapped from q[2].
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: And could you tell me why the circuit(FIG.5) measures q[2] at last? 
Is it for making sure this circuit is working?
Again, thank you for replying.